# I can't use segmentedControl when i try to remember the selection of segmented control

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

i got a problem i have a segmented control and 2 buttons.

These 2 buttons leads to table view controllers where user select inputs

but when user selects a segmented control's segment and goes to tableview controller, the selection goes back to default.

```
- (IBAction)selectionOfTransportation:(id)sender {

     ran =((UISegmentedControl *)sender).selectedSegmentIndex;
    NSLog(@"%d",ran);

    switch (ran) {
        case 0://vapur
            NSLog(@"0 ");
             path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"vapurWeekdays" ofType:@"plist"];
            arrayOfPlist = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

            ran=0;
            break;
        case 1:
             NSLog(@"1");
            path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"denizotobus" ofType:@"plist"];
            arrayOfPlist = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
            ran=1;

            break;
        case 2:

            break;
    }

    NSUserDefaults *settings = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];



    [settings setInteger:ran forKey:@"MySelectedValueKey"];

}
```

this is my code.

I saved the value into the NSUserDefaults and tried to change the selection but i can't seem to use segment.selectedSegmentIndex in anywhere!

At first i defined segmented control as an action but i even tried to define it in .h file.

how can i use it?

Or even better, how can i remember the selection of segmented control

Comment: It should happen by default...you shouldn't need to tell it which tab to highlight. Did you call this method "selectionOfTransportation" on the UIControlEventValueChanged event for your UISegmentedControl?

Comment: nope, never heard of UIControlEventValueChanged event.

I don't get it tho, are you telling that segmented control remember selection by default even tho the view control changes? @Zhang

Comment: Unless you mean your Segmented Control is inside a UIViewController that you push onto navigation stack, otherwise, your segmented control shouldn't change it's selection. Do you mean on your main page, you have a UIViewController, that has a segmented control and 2 button, you change the selected segment tab, press one of the button to push a new view controller, change some value, press back button and your segmented control resets its previously selected tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this example.

first drop and drag segment in xib.

in .h File

```
IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *mySegmentedControl;
```

in .m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

   [mySegmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];
[mySegmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentSwitch:)
                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}


- (IBAction)segmentSwitch:(id)sender
{
    int ran=mySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;

       **or**

    int ran;
    if(mySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
    {
      ran=0;
    }
    else if(mySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
    {
      ran=1;  
    }
    else if(mySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2)
    {
        ran=2;
    }
    else if(mySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 3)
    {
        ran=3;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to synchronize userdefault.
if you does not synchronize the value does not sotred

```
NSUserDefaults *settings = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[settings setInteger:ran forKey:@"MySelectedValueKey"];

//Add This Line
[settings synchronize];
```

This will synchronize userdefaults and you can use in other controllers